# Old kernel in 13.10

Tags: kernel, 13.10

I've just upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10. I've read in [some articles](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Canonical-Officially-Announces-that-Ubuntu-13-10-Is-Based-on-Linux-Kernel-3-11-391202.shtml) that Ubuntu 13.10 is supposed to have the Linux 3.11 kernel. However the output `uname -a` states that my kernel is still at 3.9:

```
Linux joren-8570w 3.9.0-030900-generic #201304291257 SMP Mon Apr 29 16:58:15 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Do I have to upgrade my kernel manually, or should this have happened / will happen in the future with the Ubuntu upgrade?

Edit: The output of `aptitude search linux | grep ^i`

```
i   libselinux1                     - SELinux runtime shared libraries          
i   libselinux1:i386                - SELinux runtime shared libraries          
i   linux-firmware                  - Firmware for Linux kernel drivers         
i A linux-headers-3.11.0-12         - Header files related to Linux kernel versi
i A linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 3.11.0 on
i   linux-headers-3.11.4-031104     - Header files related to Linux kernel versi
i   linux-headers-3.11.4-031104-gen - Linux kernel headers for version 3.11.4 on
i   linux-headers-3.9.0-030900      - Header files related to Linux kernel versi
i   linux-headers-3.9.0-030900-gene - Linux kernel headers for version 3.9.0 on 
i   linux-headers-generic           - Generic Linux kernel headers              
i   linux-image-3.9.0-030900-generi - Linux kernel image for version 3.9.0 on 64
i   linux-libc-dev                  - Linux Kernel Headers for development      
i   linux-sound-base                - base package for ALSA and OSS sound system
i   pptp-linux                      - Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol (PPTP) C
i   syslinux                        - collection of boot loaders                
i   syslinux-common                 - collection of boot loaders (common files) 
i   syslinux-legacy                 - Bootloader for Linux/i386 using MS-DOS flo
i   util-linux                      - Miscellaneous system utilities
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the custom 3.9 kernel you've installed before:

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-\.\*3\.9\.\*
```

This will remove all packages with a name matching `linux-*3.9.*`.

During the execution of `apt-get` it should reload the bootloader configuration, but just to be sure you may run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and it should list only the 3.11 kernels with Saucy.

Please note that all the time before you've been running an unpatched kernel. Avoid that next time, unless you know what you're doing, as you'll have to update the kernel yourself if you do that.

Comment: I've done all you said, but now my laptop won't start anymore. It doesn't even get to the grub. I've already tried updating the grub from a live cd.

Comment: Well, if Grub doesn't even start anymore then you have a broader issue here. Please ask a new question about this.

Comment: Alrighty http://askubuntu.com/questions/360538/laptop-wont-get-to-grub-after-meddling-with-kernels