# Laptop won't get to grub after meddling with kernels

Tags: grub2, 13.10

I recently found out I had different kernel versions installed, so I removed the 3.9 kernel as proposed in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/360439/88802) on my earlier question. After that, I updated my grub, but My laptop won't seem to reach it.

Output of `aptitude search linux | grep ^i`:

```
i   libselinux1                     - SELinux runtime shared libraries          
i   libselinux1:i386                - SELinux runtime shared libraries          
i   linux-firmware                  - Firmware for Linux kernel drivers         
i A linux-headers-3.11.0-12         - Header files related to Linux kernel versi
i A linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 3.11.0 on
i   linux-headers-3.11.4-031104     - Header files related to Linux kernel versi
i   linux-headers-3.11.4-031104-gen - Linux kernel headers for version 3.11.4 on
i   linux-headers-generic           - Generic Linux kernel headers              
i   linux-libc-dev                  - Linux Kernel Headers for development      
i   linux-sound-base                - base package for ALSA and OSS sound system
i   pptp-linux                      - Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol (PPTP) C
i   syslinux                        - collection of boot loaders                
i   syslinux-common                 - collection of boot loaders (common files) 
i   syslinux-legacy                 - Bootloader for Linux/i386 using MS-DOS flo
i   util-linux                      - Miscellaneous system utilities
```

How do I proceed to fix this error from my live cd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my own problem by working the magic of **[Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)**. I used the Live CD to automagically reinstall grub, fix my kernel mess. Only thing left to do was after I got to the login screen, reinstall my Nvidia drivers because my desktop was messed up.

I hope this can be of use for people experiencing the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do as you've identified is to reinstall grub. This ubuntuforums thread provides a lot of good information about how to use grub. Section 13 specifically gives information on how to reinstall grub.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275

When you've booted into the live CD, mount your normal system partition;
This part is important. If you have a /boot partition (check with `df -h`) make sure that's the one you use. If not, use the partition labeled `/`

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
```

Then, install grub by running the following command, notice that the previous command said sdXY, and this command just uses the volume name, sdX;

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdX
```

Then simply unmount;

```
sudo umount /mnt
```

and reboot and you should be ok again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now my laptop boots to grub, but I only get to see its CLI. What's next?